# Geocoding Error via Python and Google's Geocoding API

Tags: python, geocoding, google-geocoding-api

I am in need of some help at the moment with some research that I am working on in python. I cannot get this Geocoding API by google to work for some reason and I am not understanding the error code despite Googling that stuff.
Note: I have a dataframe that I converted into a dictionary to pass into this documentation for the Geocoding API.

The code:

```
API_KEY = 'private'  

# appending all addresses in radius_0 to the list titled addresses  

addresses = [] 
for each_dict in final_dict:     
address = final_dict['Location']     
addresses.append(address) 
print(addresses)  

# parameters  

params = {     'key': API_KEY,      'address': addresses }  

# following google documentation with the url provided for the API request  

base_url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?'  

# to see print(response) 

response = requests.get(base_url, params=params).json()  

# accessing the keys of the dictionary titled 

response  response.keys()  
if response['status'] == 'OK':      
geometry = response['results'][0]['geometry']     
lat = geometry['location']['lat']     
lon = geometry['location']['lng'] 
print((lat, lon)) 

# Error Code: 
    HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/s6/zdp5jv2j74l4k3nty81q0wrm0000gn/T/ipykernel_40787/2892721893.py in <module>
     25 
     26 response = requests.get(base_url, params=params)
---> 27 response.raise_for_status()  # raises exception when not a 2xx response
     28 if response.status_code != 204:
     29     return response.json()

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/models.py in raise_for_status(self)
    951 
    952         if http_error_msg:
--> 953             raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
    954 
    955     def close(self):

HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url:
```

Thank you very much and any help or tips are extremely appreciated!

Comment: "*I am not understanding the error code despite Googling that stuff*" Any reason you haven't provided the full error text in the body of your question? [ask]

Comment: I have updated the full error code, thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: Thanks. Can you elaborate as to how you reached the conclusion that you should be able to pass a list object with *multiple* addresses into the `address` parameter of this API? Can you point to the specific documentation item for which you are basing this implicit claim? Nothing my cursory research turns up points to the possibility of bulk-geocoding like this, and passing an incorrectly-formatted string (as a result of ostensibly implicitly converting `addresses` to a string) would indeed likely return a `400 Bad Request` response from the API itself. Why not loop over each address instead..?